# Javascript how to change output of a number to us currency with 2 decimals

Tags: javascript, decimal, currency

I want to change output of a number to US currency with 2 decimals; the JavaScript part looks like this:

```
var leagueDues = 5.00;
var CourseFees = 14.50;

var totalLeagueDues = leagueDues * 16;
var totalCourseFees = CourseFees * 16;

var totalDues = totalCourseFees + totalLeagueDues;

document.getElementById('league').value = totalLeagueDues;
document.getElementById('fee').value = totalCourseFees;
document.getElementById('total').value = totalDues;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: it's not clear what the question is. But (judging from the title) if you want to display a number (as a string) with 2 fixed decimal places (eg. `15.00` instead of just `15`), you want to use the `toFixed` method which all JS numbers have https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Answer (score 2):

You can use the toFixed(2) function to fix the number to 2 decimal places.

That would look like:

```
var leagueDues = 5.00; 
var CourseFees = 14.50; 
var totalLeagueDues = leagueDues * 16; 
var totalCourseFees = CourseFees * 16; 
var totalDues = totalCourseFees + totalLeagueDues; 

document.getElementById('league').value = totalLeagueDues.toFixed(2); 
document.getElementById('fee').value = totalCourseFees.toFixed(2); 
document.getElementById('total').value = totalDues.toFixed(2);
```